# Get String in list in adapter (gson)

Tags: json, arraylist, gson, adapter

I have a problem with my adapter. I already succeeded to display some informations from my JSON (codeLieu and libelle) that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "codeLieu": "OTAG",
        "libelle": "50 Otages",
        "distance": null,
        "ligne": [
            {
                "numLigne": "2"
            },
            {
                "numLigne": "C2"
            },
            {
                "numLigne": "12"
            },
            {
                "numLigne": "23"
            }
        ]
    },
...
]
```

Here is my model:

```
package material.romain.com.projentreprise.Adapter;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class Response implements Serializable{

    private String codeLieu;
    private String libelle;
    private String distance;
    private List<LigneEntities> ligne;


    public String getCode() {
        return codeLieu;
    }

    public void setCode(String codeLieu) {
        this.codeLieu = codeLieu;
    }

    public String getLibelle() {
        return libelle;
    }

    public void setLibelle(String libelle) {
        this.libelle = libelle;
    }

    public String getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(String distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public List<LigneEntities> getLigne() {return ligne;}

    public void setLigne(List<LigneEntities> ligne) {
        this.ligne = ligne;
    }

    public static class LigneEntities {
        private String numLigne;

        public String getLigne() {
            return numLigne;
        }

        public void setLigne(String numLigne) {
            this.numLigne = numLigne;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally this is my adapter :

```
package material.romain.com.projentreprise.Adapter;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.mikepenz.fontawesome_typeface_library.FontAwesome;
import com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;
import material.romain.com.projentreprise.R;
import material.romain.com.projentreprise.Util.CircularTextView;
import material.romain.com.projentreprise.Util.ColorLigne;

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private ArrayList<Response> arret;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private MyFilter mFilter;
    private ArrayList<Response> mSearchArret;

    public ListAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Response> mArretItem) {
        this.context = mContext;
        this.arret = mArretItem;
        this.mSearchArret = mArretItem;

        getFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mSearchArret.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mSearchArret.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Response item = (Response) getItem(position);
        ColorLigne.ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ColorLigne.ViewHolder();
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.each_list_item, parent, false);

            holder.circleImage = (CircleImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.circleView);
            holder.textArret = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvListArret);
            holder.circle = (CircularTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvArretColor);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ColorLigne.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Drawable color = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.tanVert));
        Drawable image = new IconicsDrawable(context).icon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_bus).color(Color.WHITE).sizeDp(48).paddingDp(10);

        LayerDrawable ld = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{color, image});

        holder.circleImage.setImageDrawable(ld);
        holder.textArret.setText(item.getLibelle());


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new MyFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

    class MyFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (prefix != null && prefix.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Response> tempList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (Response value : arret) {
                    if (value.getLibelle().toLowerCase().contains(prefix.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        tempList.add(value);
                    }
                }
                results.count = tempList.size();
                results.values = tempList;
            } else {
                results.count = arret.size();
                results.values = arret;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            try {
                mSearchArret = (ArrayList<Response>) results.values;
                if (results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I would like to get strings from "ligne" but it's in a list and I don't know how to access it. My goal is to put the strings into a circleTextView.

Edit: 
I tried this in getView method

```
Response item = getItem(position);
for(Response value: arret){
            value = item;
            String ligneItem = value.getLigne().toString();
            ColorLigne.setColorLigne(ligneItem, holder, context);       
            holder.circle.setText(ligneItem);
            holder.circle.setStrokeWidth(0);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below method to your `Response.java`

```
public String getItems() {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (LigneEntities entity : getLigne()) { //loop through every item from the list
        builder.append(entity.getLigne() + ","); //add to StringBuilder
    }

    builder.replace(builder.length() - 1, builder.length(), "");//remove last ,(semicolon)
    return builder.toString();
}
```

setting to your `CircleTextView`

`holder.circle.setText(item.getItems());`

Comment: Your response was very helpful, now i can display content in my text view but there is one more problem i post you a picture http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/20/1463414765-screenshot-2016-05-16-18-02-16.png In the red rectangle everything is fine because i have only one string (it's a bus line number) but in the black rectangle you can see i have many strings. My goal is to display a number in different `CircleTextView`. I think the best way is to create programmatically TextView in a foreach loop and may be create new layout and add it to the existing layout to reorganize textview.

Comment: Yes you are right.. pro-grammatically you need to create views.. use LinearLayout and add views in it.